# Bootstrap 3 responsive classes change display property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When upgrading my project from Bootstrap 2.3 to Bootstrap 3.0 I noticed that adding a responsive class, e.g. `hidden-sm` to an element, changes its CSS display property to `block`.

To make things worse, the new display property is set as `!important`, making it difficult (or at least ugly) to overwrite by custom CSS rules.

For example, the code (view result here: http://jsfiddle.net/RZ95F/)

```
<h1>
  Heading
  <small>sub-Heading</small>
</h1>
```

gives a different result than the code (view result here: http://jsfiddle.net/vTuW8/)

```
<h1>
  Heading
  <small class="hidden-sm">sub-Heading</small>
</h1>
```

namely adding a line-break between the heading and the sub-heading.

Of course, this strange behavior also applies to much more complicated cases, making it very hard for me to upgrade my project without major markup and CSS changes just to compensate for this new Bootstrap behavior.

What did the Bootstrap team try to accomplish by changing the `display` behavior of those elements? And is there an easy workaround to restore the behavior known from Bootstrap 2.3 and earlier?

Comment: "Responsive utilities are currently only available for block and table toggling. Use with inline and table elements is currently not supported." from http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Well, great. This is a bug that should have been resolved in alpha stadium, or at least during one of the betas. They should be ashamed to call this a final version!

Answer (score 2):

This is tracked on GitHub as [#8869](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8869). A simple workaround shown there is to add a separate inline helper class:

```
.hidden-inline-xs {
    display: inline !important;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-inline-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Then you can just use

```
<h1>
  Heading
  <small class="hidden-inline-xs">sub-Heading</small>
</h1>
```